# Java OpenGL is not drawing vertical lines correct

Tags: java, opengl

After many tests I always got the same wrong result while drawing a vertical line on the canvas. It looks like they are drawn twice and dotted next to each other.

[This is the error while drawing a vertical line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mQ4l.png)

There was no error when drawing horizontal lines. They looked like expected.

```
package FirstTest;

import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class OpenGLTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
  
    final GLProfile gp = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
    GLCapabilities cap = new GLCapabilities(gp);

    final GLCanvas gc = new GLCanvas(cap);
    gc.addGLEventListener(new GLEventHandler());
    gc.setSize(400, 400);

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOGL Line");
    frame.add(gc);
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);   
}

    private static class GLEventHandler implements GLEventListener {

        @Override
        public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
            final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        
            gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.4f, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.4f, 0.4f, 0);
            gl.glEnd();
        }

        @Override
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {}

        @Override
        public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {}
    }
}
```

This is the code I use. I found similar examples on websites but none of them worked like I want or like I was excepting.

I implented the OpenGL ressources by using Maven.
This is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>3DMaven</groupId>
<artifactId>3DMaven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>12</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You might want to mention what package you are using.  None of the `javax.media.opengl` packages are standard (at least for me).  Is it from this site? https://jogamp.org/

Comment: I implemented it with Maven dependencies. I took them from [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all-main/2.3.2) and a second dependency from [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt-main/2.3.2).